# Accessing a JSON value that references another JSONs key

Tags: json, object-reference, value-objects

I have two JSON files and one references the other.

The first file below is parsed into the program as *moves*, it's referencing into a spritesheet.

```
{"stand": { "x":  0, "y": 12, "width": 49, "height": 52 },
 "walk1": { "x": 52, "y": 12, "width": 50, "height": 52 }}
```

Then I define another object *dong* as a key value pair like below

```
doing = { frame: [{sprite:moves.stand, xoff:  0, yoff:102},
                  {sprite:moves.walk, xoff: 10, yoff:102} ]}
```

And can reference the data as **doing.frame[0].sprite.x** and all is good.

My problems start when I try to make the **doing** object as a JSON file as it requires the value sprite to be a string and not an object reference.

```
{frame:[{"sprite":"moves.stand", "xoff":  0, "yoff":102},
         "sprite":"moves.stand", "xoff": 10, "yoff":122}]}
```

Is there a way to define an object reference for JSON or
a way to convert the string "moves.stand" back into an object reference?

I have managed to use a single word string reference but not a dot syntax reference.  But not with the dot notation.

```
{frame:[{"sprite":"stand", "xoff": 0, "yoff":102},
        {"sprite":"walk0", "xoff": 64, "yoff":102}]}


 moves[doing.frame[0].sprite].x
```

Answer (score 2):

You can save `JSON.stringify(doing)` content to your file.

```js
var moves = {"stand": { "x": 0, "y": 12, "width": 49, "height": 52 }}


var doing = {
    "frame": [{"sprite":moves.stand, "xoff":  0, "yoff":102},
            {"sprite":moves.stand, "xoff": 10, "yoff":122} ]
}  

console.log(JSON.stringify(doing));
```

Comment: Thanks, that works but I lose readability that the object reference provides as the moes.stand is replaced with  "x": 0, "y": 12, "width": 49, "height": 52 data

Comment: you can compare with your moves.stand after you parse file to object by JSON.parse

Comment: It does help with read ability.  If I have "stand" instead "moves.stand" then I can moves[doing.frame[0].sprite].x  as the string can be a reference.  But not with "moves.stand" and  [doing.frame[0].sprite].x  The reason to not have the two json files combine is I only need one change in the moves file and it will be updated vi all references and integration would mean a heap of editing.  Still thanks as it's help me work out a kind of fix with single word string references.